# Unhandled win32 exception occurred in "php.exe" in command line

Tags: php, cakephp, command-line, pear

When I try to do anything with PHP in the command line, the command line crashes and throws an "unhandled win32 exception". However, my websites are executing PHP without errors.

When I debug using Visual Studio, the program breaks at this line in php.exe:

```
100E890C  mov         edx,dword ptr [edx+4]
```

And the call stack is as follows:

```
>php5ts.dll!100e890c()  
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for php5ts.dll]    
msvcrt.dll!761eade8()   
msvcrt.dll!761ec470()   
msvcrt.dll!761ef637()   
php.exe!00402e5b()  
kernel32.dll!77211194()     
ntdll.dll!7799b429()    
ntdll.dll!7799b3fc()
```

I need to be able to work with PHP in the command line for installing PEAR extensions and for CakePHP functions. However, I don't know how to fix this problem...

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your PHP to the latest version and try again. Looks like a bug in php itself.

Comment: @weedave did upgrading solve your crash? I am facing the same issue with PHP 5.1.1

Comment: 5.1.1 is long, long dead. There are several bugfix versions for 5.1.x, too.

Comment: I know but it is a production server not controlled by me or my company and currently hosting several websites. Sadly not too much I can do beside telling them to upgrade

Comment: 5.1.1 does not get security updates since several years now, so running it is a security problem itself.