# an unhandled win32 exception occurred in httpd.exe in php

Tags: php, windows, imagemagick

I have a hard time to install imagemagick for PHP.

I used `ImageMagick-6.7.7-8-Q16-windows-dll.exe` and added `php_imagick.dll` into my php `ext` folder and `phpinfo` is showing php_imagick extention.

I am on Windows XP using Wamp Server 2.1, PHP 5.3.5, Apache 2.2.17, Mysql 5.5.8

When I run the following code it is resulting in an unhandled win32 exception occurred in `httpd.exe`:

```
try
{
    $image = 'exists.jpg';

    /*** a new imagick object ***/
    $im = new Imagick($image);

    echo 'Imagick';
}
catch(Exception $e) 
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Help me in achieving this problem.

Comment: You already have unlocked this problem and gained the *"httpd.exe win32 unhandled exception"* achievement. Congratulations! Can you please try to trigger it as well on the commandline? See [Unhandled win32 exception occurred in “php.exe” in command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5370117/367456)

Answer (score 0):

Seems corrupt installation, what's your OS version and have you met any error when installing?

Please upload your logs by referring to this blog

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2009/05/20/collect.aspx

And use this tool to collect log http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=8967043

After running this tool please upload this log to skydrive and share me the link for troubleshoot.

Additionally, have you tried uninstall Visual Studio with this tool:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall

With Complete command

Thanks,